# coffeescript analog of try() activesupport method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, activesupport

There is extremely useful `.try()` rails method, which helps me a lot with functions like that:

```
hash.try(:a).try(:b)
# equal to
# if hash.present? && hash.a.present?
#   hash.a.b
# else
#   nil
# end
```

Is there anything similar to that in coffeescript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes:

```
hash?.a?.b
```

See `the existential operator` in [the doc](http://coffeescript.org/)